# What is the definition of twirled superoperator?

Tags: quantum-operation

I am trying find the definition of twirled (super)operator. One such is Definition 2.3.16 on p. 33 of [Christoph Dankert, *Efficient Simulation of Random Quantum States and Operators*](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0512217). However, the notations puzzles me.

1. What does $\Lambda(V^\dagger XV)$ mean?
2. How do the two integrals apparently both involving $\Lambda_T$ relate to each other?

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/23845/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6255/55

Answer (score 2):

1. $X$ is a density matrix. $V^\dagger X V$ is another density matrix. $\Lambda$ is a channel that takes one density matrix to another density matrix. So $\Lambda(V^\dagger X V)$ means take the density matrix $V^\dagger X V$ and apply the channel $\Lambda$ to it.
2. The two integrals are two ways to write the same formula. In the first, they use the Liouville operators $\hat V:=V\otimes V^*$ and $\hat\Lambda$ to define the Liouville operator version of the twirled channel $\hat\Lambda_T$. In the second, they use the channel notation $\Lambda(\cdot)$ to define the twirled channel $\Lambda_T(\cdot)$. If you just follow the definition of the Liouville operator, you can see that the Liouville operator of the thing they define as $\Lambda_T$ is indeed what they define as $\hat \Lambda_T$.

Comment: 1) How is $\hat\Lambda$ defined? Is it the following? Given $V\in U(d), \hat\Lambda(X):=\Lambda(VXV^\dagger), \forall$ density operator $X$. Note in this setting the $\hat\cdot$ operator is dependent on $V$.  2) How does the tensor product definition of $\hat V$ reconcile with the second definition of $\Lambda_T(X)$ which is defined in the non-tensor space?

Comment: @Hans That is not how $\hat\Lambda$ is defined. $\hat\Lambda$ is a linear superoperator matrix, or Liouville matrix. The basic idea is that we know $\Lambda$ is a linear operator on the $d^2$-dimensional space of density matrices, so if you pick a basis for that space you can write $\Lambda$ as a $d^2\times d^2$ matrix. That matrix is $\hat\Lambda$. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.2539.pdf, in particular III.B

Comment: @Hans Although honestly, you could do better by just reading this answer, I think it's clearer than the paper I linked https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6646/9438